# I need to convert ext2 filesystem to ext4 to prevent fsck every time I boot?

Tags: 12.10, boot, filesystem, ext4, fsck

Installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside manufacturer-installed Win 8 with no problems. Was "clever" enough to install as ext2 filesystem, which has resulted in the inconvenience of fsck making the usual checks every time I boot up. Sure, I could just press "C" to cancel the check, but that gets a little old after a while.

I've already tried tinkering with the maximum mount count in tune2fs, but that hasn't made any difference. It looks like I have to convert my ext2 filesystem to ext4. I could do this via the information provided [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/11/convert-ext23-to-ext4/) but have also noticed that I can enable some of the features of ext4, as detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211069/how-to-convert-ext2-to-ext4), by running the following command...

```
sudo tune2fs -O has_journal,uninit_bg,extents /dev/sda1
```

...and rebooting.

Is it necessary to do the full filesystem conversion, or will the fsck be eliminated by running the above command in terminal to enable some ext4 features?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do that from a live environment (launch from a Ubuntu DVD or pendrive). Before doing so, please check the filesystem:

```
sudo fsck.ext2 /dev/sda1
```

And then do your thing. You better also enable `dir_index`. You can read about ext4 features [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4). Do it:

```
sudo tune2fs -O dir_index,has_journal,uninit_bg,extents /dev/sda1
```

After doing that, try mounting the filesystem to see if everything is OK.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt -t ext4
```

Can you see the filesystem? Nice.

```
sudo ls /mnt
```

And that's enough to convert the filesystem. But you'll also need to change the file `/etc/fstab` for the operating system to mount the filesystem as ext4.

```
sudo gedit /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Change the second line to say `ext4` instead of `ext2`:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=14f577b8-xxxx-4124-88d3-c1d49eb41113 /               ext2    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

And that's it. Save and exit. Don't forget to unmount the filesystem before restarting into your system again:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: Thank you :-) does this remove the need for refreshing Grub on my boot partition, as in step 6 at http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/11/convert-ext23-to-ext4/?

Comment: You shouldn't need to refresh Grub at all. If the system don't boot, go back to the live environment and do it, though.

Comment: It's better to use sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep "Filesystem features" to get full option list from another ext4 (if you have it) instead of copying them from web.

Comment: @lampslave you have a point, but in case you don't have it, these options are a good default.